# How to get one of random index from an array in love2d

Tags: arrays, random, lua, love2d

I am working on a project that i have select a random index from an array that i created. Here the array

```
kotak = { 
    love.graphics.newImage('images/1.png'),
    love.graphics.newImage('images/2.png')
  }
```

And i want to get one of the index of this array, and my code like this

```
randomKotak = love.math.random(#kotak)  
love.graphics.draw(kotak[randomKotak], 200,200, 0.05 , 1, 1, 16, 16)
```

but i get the result is value of index is always changing. 
how i can get only one of the index. no changing.

Comment: `randomKotak = randomKotak or love.math.random(#kotak)`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Egor Skriptunoff posted, you can do something like this:

```
-- code...
randomKotak = randomKotak or love.math.random(#kotak)
love.graphics.draw(kotak[randomKotak], 200, 200, 0.05, 1, 1, 16, 16)
-- code...
```

The reason this works is because the `or` operator in Lua will return the first operand if it resolves to true, or the second operand if not. When first run, `randomKotak` is `nil`, resolving to false. This causes `randomKotak` to be set to the second operand (the randomizer). The next time it's run `randomKotak` will be a number, which Lua resolves to true, causing `randomKotak` to be set to itself.

One problem with this code is that it creates a global variable, which could cause problems later. It may be better to add a local at the root level in your code (outside of the function/loop), changing the code to something like this:

```
local randomKotak = nil
function drawKotak() -- or whatever the function's called
    -- code...
    randomKotak = randomKotak or love.math.random(#kotak)
    love.graphics.draw(kotak[randomKotak], 200, 200, 0.05, 1, 1, 16, 16)
    -- code...
end
```

This will make it so code in other files won't disrupt this function.